# Non-rigorous (maybe a good pop-math) book about real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am reading a real analysis book at the moment, but I feel the lack of something I believe that could be a good feature: Historical remarks about the concepts and also some *chat* about how those concepts are interconnected. I'm self-studying and most of the time I don't have someone to talk about those concepts - I would like to read some insights about the introduced concepts.

The only book I know that is similar to what I'm look is [Analysis by Its history](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387770313). Are there more books such as this one?

I'm reading [Derbyshire's *Unknown Quantity*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0452288533) - for example. It would be nice to have a resource that talks about the concepts in analysis such as this book. I'm not looking specifically for a textbook on real analysis, it could be a non-serious book to be read together with a textbook. It's nice to have an idea of how the things are interconnected without spending hours trying to grasp the precise meaning of the concept.

Answer (score 2):

[The Calculus Gallery](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691136262) by Dunham is great.

Answer (score 1):

There was another user who posted a nice suggeston:

- [David Applebaum's: Limits, Limits Everywhere](http://ukcatalogue.oup.com/product/9780199640089.do).

But he erased his answer for unknown reasons. I've reposted so others can see the suggestion. I've also discovered some other books which are nice examples similar to what I was looking for:

- [From the Calculus to Set Theory 1630-1910:An Introductory History](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/6939.html).

It discusses the historical motivation of calculus and the rising of analysis. Another really nice book is:

- [The Real Numbers: An Introduction to Set Theory and Analysis](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-3-319-01576-7).

It is a perfect introduction to analysis, full of historical remarks and motivation for the topics given in the book. A really astounding book!

Comment: To this list I would add David M. Bressoud's [**A Radical Approach to Real Analysis**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0883857472).